# Not able to capture time difference using a .bat file

Tags: windows, batch-file, vbscript, cmd

I have a bat file which I am using to generate a LOG  file, and in the log file, I am trying to capture the starting time and ending time for every for loop. I am not able to get any different values whenever I want to `echo %TIME%` using my bat file. The first timestamp that the bat file captures is displayed through out the program.
The bat file created by me is as follows:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS

SET me=%~n0

SET parentPath=%~dp0

cd C:\Users\bangshis\Desktop\TOOLS\New Folder

ECHO %me% : Creating file for logging time>myTimeLog.txt

ECHO  %me% : STARTING CONVERSION: %TIME%>>myTimeLog.txt

for %%a in ("C:\MyData\Work\InputFiles\TextFiles\*.txt") do (SETLOCAL

set STARTTIME=%TIME%

ECHO  %me% : TIME STARTING CONVERSION: %STARTTIME% >>myTimeLog.txt

ECHO  %me% : The File getting processed is: %%a >>myTimeLog.txt

textToDOC.bat %%a "C:\Work\Output_Dir\%%~na"

ENDLOCAL

SETLOCAL

set ENDTIME=%TIME%

ECHO  %me% : TIME ENDING CONVERSION: %ENDTIME% >>myTimeLog.txt

ENDLOCAL

)

ECHO  %me% : ENDING CONVERSION: %TIME%>>myTimeLog.txt

pause>nul
```

#### Output:

```
textToDOC_conv : Creating file for logging time

textToDOC_conv : STARTING CONVERSION: 13:28:28.99

textToDOC_conv : TIME STARTING CONVERSION: 13:28:28.99 

textToDOC_conv : The File getting processed is: C:\Work\InputFiles\Test\PLS.txt 

textToDOC_conv : TIME ENDING CONVERSION: 13:28:28.99 

textToDOC_conv : TIME STARTING CONVERSION: 13:28:28.99 

textToDOC_conv : The File getting processed is: C:\Work\InputFiles\Test\X2Q.txt
```

Kindly let me know, why i am getting the same timestamp every time I am trying to publish?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SETLOCAL enabledelayedexpansion
SET me=%~n0
SET parentPath=%~dp0
cd C:\Users\bangshis\Desktop\TOOLS\New Folder
ECHO %me% : Creating file for logging time>myTimeLog.txt
ECHO  %me% : STARTING CONVERSION: %TIME%>>myTimeLog.txt

for %%a in ("C:\MyData\Work\InputFiles\TextFiles\*.txt") do (SETLOCAL
ECHO  %me% : TIME STARTING CONVERSION: !TIME! >>myTimeLog.txt
ECHO  %me% : The File getting processed is: %%a >>myTimeLog.txt
textToDOC.bat %%a "C:\Work\Output_Dir\%%~na"
ECHO  %me% : TIME ENDING CONVERSION: !Time! >>myTimeLog.txt
)

ECHO  %me% : ENDING CONVERSION: %TIME%>>myTimeLog.txt
pause>nul
```

When you want to use variables in a code block (That is code between `(` and `)`) You need to `enabledelayedexpansion` and use exclamation marks instead of percentage signs.

Since `%me%` is constant throughout the code you can use `%` for it without having any issues

Comment: Hi, I tried the modifications that you mentioned. But I am still getting the starting and ending conversations to be same.

Comment: One more update to this is time variable is not getting displayed inside the FOR look and it is appearing as !Time! in the LOG file too.